# using hasClass() to display matching list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question from JavaScript newbie.
I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="class1 class2"> </li>
<li class="class3 class4"> </li>
<li class="class1 class3"> </li>
</ul>
```

All list items are initially hidden, and I need to check if an item has a certain class to show it. And if several items contain one class, I need to show them all. The problem is, I don't know how to target the elements correctly:

```
if ($('li').hasClass('class3')) {
/* show this li */
}
```

What should I write here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('class3')) {
        //do what you need, 'this' is your li
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

That won't work, as `hasClass` <s>only checks the first li</s> returns whether any of the `li`s have the class. Just do this:

```
$('li.class3').show()
```

Another way of writing it, if your conditions get more complex, is:

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('class3');
}).show()
```

Comment: this is more simple than mine and needs to be chosen if you need nothing but show the `li`s. but if you want something more complicated, you need to iterate.

Comment: The documentation says, `hasClass` checks all selected elements whether there are any that have that class. Are are right that it won't help, but it does not only test the first one ;)

Comment: ok, but if I'm using `if` statement, how do I target the element which is in the condition? Say,  `if ($('li.class1').hasClass('class3')) { ... } ` how to target this li?

Comment: `$('li.class1.class3')`. See my answer for a more general solution

Comment: @Eric: sorry, my comment should have been directed at Michael. You've done exactly what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('class3')){
       //Do stuff
    }
}).show()
```

Comment: What does  `this` refer to here?

Comment: @Feliz: The window, I believe!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$('li.class3').css('display','block');
if($('li.class3').size()>3)
{
$('li').css('display','block');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add it, and remove it from the siblings:
This is the best way.

```
$("li").on("click", function(){
  $(this)
    .addClass("className")
    .siblings()
      .removeClass("className");
});
```